# Who was the most beautiful wife of Prophet Muhammad?

Tags: hadith, prophet-muhammad, husband-wife

I just can't come to a conclusion reading from the sources. I see the competition was (in my understanding) between Aishah bint Abu Bakr, Safiyya bint Huyaiy, Maria Qibtiyya and Juweirya.

For instance, it has been narrated that Aishah mentioned a kind of jealous remark of the other three in terms of beauty. But the Prophet always put Aishah as his most beautiful wife? I do not understand.

Please give some narrations to support your views, Jazak Allah.

Comment: What is the relevance of this to Islam?

Comment: @TheZ one could easily answer this with a reference to seerah/history and biographies. Nevertheless the answer of a question about a woman's beauty is strictly speaking subjective. If you want to know about the prophet's preference then most ahadith tend to point at 'Aishah as the woman he regarded as the most beuatiful among his wives.

Comment: @Sassir One *could* answer it like that although I do not myself remember any hadith where the Prophet (SAW) talked about whom he regarded as most beautiful. However, I don't think this has any relevance to Islam unless the OP clarifies.

Comment: @TheZ I think sassir is referring to the ahadith where the prophet calls her al-Humayra' الحميراء which is a kind of expression to address the beauty of her skin.

Answer (score 1):

All women were/are beautiful but you need an eye to see/compliment their beauty. There's no need to draw your conclusions that who was the most beautiful one.